# Кроссплатформенная работа с USB

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, usb

Исходно есть `Linux` и `Windows` приложение основанные на `Qt`, задача заключается в  том чтобы с помощью этих приложений в момент подключения `USB` накопителя открывать определенный каталог на накопителе. Вопрос : Какой инструментарий лучше использовать чтобы без проблем собирать один и тот же проект на обеих системах?

**P.S.** Про `libusb` вкурсе, но не знаю на сколько он подходит для поддержания кросслатформености проекта.

Comment: libusb - это явно не то, что нужно. Это инструмент для низкоуровневой работы с протоколом USB, обычно используется при разработке самодельных usb-устройств.

Comment: Вообще, даже средствами Qt это кроссплатформенно не сделать. Для Linux могу предложить мониторинг каталога `/dev/` с помощью [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html).

Comment: @maestro, про мониторинг каталогов это и так понятно. Накопал в интернетах токую штуку, но сильно не тестировал http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/aboutus.php  вроде как внятное api для работы с usb на разных платформах. Как проведу все тесты отпишу.

Comment: Не проще ли написать свой модуль? Универсальный хедер и специфические обработчики под каждую ОС. Буквально страничка-две текста. У меня так подключение HID-устройства под виндой и макос проверяется.

Comment: @AlexeyEsaulenko, кажется к этому дело и идет, но ёкотпус и так имеет универсальные модули и кажется выбор остановиться на нем.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450160/usb-programming-with-qt

Comment: Думаю вопрос можно закрыть. Выбор пал на ёктопус с парой допилок.

Comment: напишите ответ закройте вопрос